# Bitcoins purchased in 2013

Tags: recover-private-key

I purchased Bitcoin in either 2012 or 2013 and at the time noted down 2 sets of 34-character addresses each with a 12 character password, both 34 character strings start with a "1".

I'm not holding out much hope that I can retrieve them, but can anyone explain what these details might be.

I can't remember logging into anything at the time.

Comment: When you write "12 character password" did you actually mean a 12 **word** *passphrase*?

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid that if you only have the addresses and not the corresponding private keys you're out of luck here.

To recover a wallet or an address you need to have either the wallet.dat or the private key to a Bitcoin address.

The password you made back then was likely used to encrypt the wallet.dat.